# callvalue opcode, for what?

Tags: evm, opcode, bytecode

someone know what the opcode CALLVALUE is for? 
I would like to understand it well.
Have you an example on which I can easily understand it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a contract call occurs, it receives some parameters on the stack, among these parameters, `Value` contains the amount of ETH this contract will receive to make some operations with it.

The `emv.Call` function looks like this:

```
func (evm *EVM) Call(caller ContractRef, addr common.Address, input []byte, gas uint64, value *big.Int) (ret []byte, leftOverGas uint64, err error) {
    if evm.vmConfig.NoRecursion && evm.depth > 0 {
        return nil, gas, nil
    }

    // Fail if we're trying to execute above the call depth limit
    if evm.depth > int(params.CallCreateDepth) {
        return nil, gas, ErrDepth
    }
    // Fail if we're trying to transfer more than the available balance
    if !evm.Context.CanTransfer(evm.StateDB, caller.Address(), value) {
        return nil, gas, ErrInsufficientBalance
    }

    var (
        to       = AccountRef(addr)
        snapshot = evm.StateDB.Snapshot()
    )
    if !evm.StateDB.Exist(addr) {
        precompiles := PrecompiledContractsHomestead
        if evm.ChainConfig().IsByzantium(evm.BlockNumber) {
            precompiles = PrecompiledContractsByzantium
        }
        if precompiles[addr] == nil && evm.ChainConfig().IsEIP158(evm.BlockNumber) && value.Sign() == 0 {
            // Calling a non existing account, don't do antything, but ping the tracer
            if evm.vmConfig.Debug && evm.depth == 0 {
                evm.vmConfig.Tracer.CaptureStart(caller.Address(), addr, false, input, gas, value)
                evm.vmConfig.Tracer.CaptureEnd(ret, 0, 0, nil)
            }
            return nil, gas, nil
        }
        evm.StateDB.CreateAccount(addr)
    }
    evm.Transfer(evm.StateDB, caller.Address(), to.Address(), value)

    // Initialise a new contract and set the code that is to be used by the EVM.
    // The contract is a scoped environment for this execution context only.
    contract := NewContract(caller, to, value, gas)
    contract.SetCallCode(&addr, evm.StateDB.GetCodeHash(addr), evm.StateDB.GetCode(addr))

    start := time.Now()

    // Capture the tracer start/end events in debug mode
    if evm.vmConfig.Debug && evm.depth == 0 {
        evm.vmConfig.Tracer.CaptureStart(caller.Address(), addr, false, input, gas, value)

        defer func() { // Lazy evaluation of the parameters
            evm.vmConfig.Tracer.CaptureEnd(ret, gas-contract.Gas, time.Since(start), err)
        }()
    }
    ret, err = run(evm, contract, input)

    // When an error was returned by the EVM or when setting the creation code
    // above we revert to the snapshot and consume any gas remaining. Additionally
    // when we're in homestead this also counts for code storage gas errors.
    if err != nil {
        evm.StateDB.RevertToSnapshot(snapshot)
        if err != errExecutionReverted {
            contract.UseGas(contract.Gas)
        }
    }
    return ret, contract.Gas, err
}
```

If you note, it gets the `Value` in parameters and stores it in the contract struct:

```
// Contract represents an ethereum contract in the state database. It contains
// the the contract code, calling arguments. Contract implements ContractRef
type Contract struct {
    // CallerAddress is the result of the caller which initialised this
    // contract. However when the "call method" is delegated this value
    // needs to be initialised to that of the caller's caller.
    CallerAddress common.Address
    caller        ContractRef
    self          ContractRef

    jumpdests destinations // result of JUMPDEST analysis.

    Code     []byte
    CodeHash common.Hash
    CodeAddr *common.Address
    Input    []byte

    Gas   uint64
    value *big.Int

    Args []byte

    DelegateCall bool
}
```

This is where the `Value` is stored:

```
value *big.Int
```

Now in `evm.Call()` function you see this line:

```
contract := NewContract(caller, to, value, gas)
```

This function stores the `Value` for further execution:

```
// NewContract returns a new contract environment for the execution of EVM.
func NewContract(caller ContractRef, object ContractRef, value *big.Int, gas uint64) *Contract {
    c := &Contract{CallerAddress: caller.Address(), caller: caller, self: object, Args: nil}

    if parent, ok := caller.(*Contract); ok {
        // Reuse JUMPDEST analysis from parent context if available.
        c.jumpdests = parent.jumpdests
    } else {
        c.jumpdests = make(destinations)
    }

    // Gas should be a pointer so it can safely be reduced through the run
    // This pointer will be off the state transition
    c.Gas = gas
    // ensures a value is set
    c.value = value

    return c
}
```

When the EVM encounters a CALLVALUE opcode, it gets this `Value` previously stored in the `Contract` struct:

```
func opCallValue(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {
    stack.push(evm.interpreter.intPool.get().Set(contract.value))
    return nil, nil
}
```

So, in short, `CALLVALUE` gives you the amount of ETH transferred to the contract by parent contract, or transaction. Sorry for so long explanation.

Answer (score 1):

in assembly you have no access to `msg.value` instead `callvalue()` is used

when we deploy contract with `create` opcode, incase transaction includes eth, we access this value with `callvalue()`

```
assembly{
        create(callvalue(), add(bytecode,0x20),mload(bytecodecode))          
    }
```